# Keep home folder from OpenSuse 12 to Leap

Tags: system-installation, opensuse, home

I currently run OpenSuse 12.3 (Dartmouth) and since it is no longer supported I would like to perform a clean install for latest OpenSuse Leap and keep my existing files inside home folder. I have a separate "home" partition. If during the installation I keep the home partition and do not format it, will I get compatibility problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could run into compability problems if config files change their format or if you have plugins included in your dotfiles (e.g. firefox).

Just give it a try. I've used the same home directory on a dual boot system for Arch and openSuSe and went well with it.

You should watch out for files like `.xinitrc` where typically a window manager is specified. So be sure you have all applications installed that are referenced by scripts in your home directory.

If you plan to do some clean up though, I would backup my home directory first, start out with a fresh one to have sane defaults and then copy over only the stuff I need.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to check device related to home.

```
df /home
Filesystem     1K-blocks   Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda3       95164008 368388  94795620   1% /home
```

in this case /dev/sda3.

During the install you will be given a choice to select partitionning. 
([see official documentation](https://activedoc.opensuse.org/book/opensuse-start-up/chapter-1-installation-quick-start) §6)

Note

1. that `/` must be at least 20 Gb.
2. If you have time, disk and memory, you may try install/upgrade on a virtual host.
3. You may also retrieve leap repository and do an upgrade.